# Issue with One to Many on MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

New to EF, MVC, and databases in general. If this is overly obvious just tell me what this is called exactly and I'd be glad to look it up on here.

I'm not able to apply information calculated from my `Foreign Key` to my `Primary key`.
In other words: I'm trying to calculate and apply a new `AmountMade` by a booth each time we "Sell" an Antique.
Booth Model:

```
public class Booth
{

    public Booth()
    {
       Antiques = new List<Antique>();
    }

    [Required]
    public int BoothId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    public double  AmountMade { get; set; }

    public Antique Antique {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Antique> Antiques{get;set;}
}
```

Antique Model:

```
public class Antique
{
    [Required]
    public int AntiqueId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public bool Sold { get; set; }

    public int BoothId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BoothId")]
    public virtual Booth Booth { get; set; }
}
```

AntiquesController:

```
    // GET: Antiques/Sell/5
    public ActionResult Sell(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Antique antique = db.Antiques.Find(id);
         antique.Booth.AmountMade = antique.Booth.AmountMade + antique.Price;   //Price of antique is added to Amount made 
        if (antique == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

         ViewBag.BoothId = new SelectList(db.Booths, "BoothId", "Owner", antique.BoothId);

        return View(antique);
    }

    // POST: Antiques/Sell/5

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Sell([Bind(Include = "AntiqueId,ItemName,Price,BoothId")] Antique antique)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(antique).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        } 
        antique.Sold = true;                                                    //Mark as sold
        ViewBag.BoothId = new SelectList(db.Booths, "BoothId", "Owner", antique.BoothId); 
        antique.Booth.AmountMade = antique.Booth.AmountMade + antique.Price;   //Price of antique is added to Amount made 

        return View(antique);
    }
```

Comment: I have a few questions. 1. The GET method returns a view called "Sell" which has a Sell button or some way to post the selling information, is that correct? If so, why are you updating the AmountMade in GET and POST? 2. In the Post method, you check if the modelstate is valid and update the  antique model but changes made to AmountMade and the property "Sold" are out of the if condition, why is that? The updation to AmountMade will never be saved since you have not called savechanges after that.

Comment: Ok.  It was my understanding that I should use the POST/GET so that I could click a link "Sell" right beside Edit and delete links, for ease of use for the user.  But it sounds like you're saying is that it would make more sense to use a button that calls a method instead of doing this all in a Post/Get?

Comment: If I could make a button that calls something that'd be great! Will this fix my issue with the changes not being properly saved in the Booth model? (It's just strange to me bc it succesfully creates the antiwue but doesnt update the booth)

Comment: "The updation to AmountMade will never be saved since you have not called savechanges after that. " You have to call db.Savechanges() to save your changes to db entities. That's first. Secondly, I did not ask you remove GET/ POST, I am asking what is your GET method expected to do and what is POST method expected to do? Are you clear about that? If so, why is your GET method making changes to AMountMade, your GET method should get the data and display the view, not make changes to entities.Third, whether you use button or an anchor tag or an ActionLink for Sellit does not make any difference.

Comment: You need to handle that click event and POST the correct data.Fourth, I still don't know why is you AmountMade being updated outside the if condition?

Comment: Sounds like I erroneously left some of the code in the GET portion.  Maybe I should just put everything in a new method that gets called by a button. That might help me to gather my thoughts and learn whats actually going on!

Comment: do not forget to db.savchanges() after you are done with db entity updates

Comment: Theres an error that highlights "  antique.Booth.AmountMade = antique.Booth.AmountMade + antique.Price; "

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in AntiqueMall.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

This synchronization happens after `Db.SaveChanges()` is called, but I'm not sure can it be done before that by calling some other method.